# How to change/edit a specific VoiceChannel's name to show server member count

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I need help to edit the name of the voice channel. I've tried everything in my power to research and find the answer, but nobody has the same problem as me :/ 
**Code:**

```
async def member_count():
            activeServers = bot.servers
            channel = bot.get_channel(549692930294677525) #Collects the voicechannel id I want to change name on
            sum = 0
            for s in activeServers:
                sum += len(s.members)
            await bot.edit_channel(channel, name="MEMBERS: {}".format(int(sum))) #Here am I trying to edit the channels name to "MEMBERS: (number of members in the server atm)"
            await asyncio.sleep(1) #Sleeps for one second before running the code again

    bot.loop.create_task(member_count()) #Creates a loop for the code above
```

**Error message:**

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<member_count() done, defined at C:\Users\bjha0\desktop\koding\bot.py:26> exception=AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'topic'",)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bjha0\desktop\koding\bot.py", line 32, in member_count
    await bot.edit_channel(channel, name="MEMBERS: {}".format(int(sum)))
  File "C:\Users\bjha0\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 2007, in edit_channel
    options[key] = getattr(channel, key)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'topic'
```

Comment: Try adding the `bot.loop.create_task(member_count())` to your `on_ready` event

Comment: What version of discord.py are you using?  Your id may need to be a string.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh since he is using `await bot.edit_channel`, this is the `async` branch. `rewrite` would use`await channel.edit`. Thus, id needs to be a string.

Comment: @Tristo Still the same error :(

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I am using Python version 3.6

Comment: Change the `id` for `get_channel` to a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to work perfectly, for me at least.

async 0.16.12:

```
async def members():
    activeServers = bot.servers
    channel = bot.get_channel("<channel id here>")
    sum = 0
    for s in activeServers:
        sum += len(s.members)
    await bot.edit_channel(channel, name="❎ MEMBERS: {} ❎".format(int(sum)))
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await members()

@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    await members()
```

rewrite 1.3.3:

```
async def members():
    activeGuilds = bot.guilds
    channel = bot.get_channel(<channel id here>)
    sum = 0
    for s in activeGuilds:
        sum += len(s.members)
    await channel.edit(name='❎ MEMBERS: {} ❎'.format(int(sum)))
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await members()

@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    await members()
```